# how to show loading image in telerik grid using asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can you please show me a sample code of loading image during data binding using telerik grid asp.net mvc Razor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the client events for OnDataBinding and OnDataBound. I would show a loading spinner when the OnDataBinding starts, then hide it again when the next method is called.

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("Grid_onDataBinding")
                                  .OnDataBound("Grid_onDataBound")) %>
```

And then, the javascript would be:

```
function Grid_onDataBinding(e) {
    $("#spinner").show();
}

function Grid_onDataBound(e) {
    $("#spinner").hide();
}
```